# Can I get command history within one directory?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, history

In Mac terminal, is there a way to get command history within a specific directory??

I know using `history` we can get the log of previous commands. But I only want the log within a specific directory. I want to see what I did in this folder previously.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. Command history isn't linked to directories.

Comment: question from ages. not withs standard

Comment: Maybe grep the output of history for `cd.*<folder-name>` and retrieve the lines until next cd or exit?

Comment: I would also find this very useful.  I have different applications in different directories that all have their specific commands for starting/stopping them.  So seeing just the commands I typed while in that directory would be helpful.  @user:3703783   Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash offers no out-of-the-box way for directory-specific history files.

My solution would be to hook into the `cd` command and change the `HISTFILE` variable, denoting the current history file. This is left as an exercise for the reader since I myself would be rather annoyed to lose my most recent history with each `cd` and it is well possible that once you get this function going you'll not want to use it.

What is your actual problem? History too big? Then don't scroll through it, but **search** it. For example with `alias r='fc -e -'` you can repeat the last command starting with `foo` by typing `r foo`. Or enter vi mode (ESC) and then search with `/foo`.

Comment: You can also repeat the last command starting with `foo` by typing `!foo`. No need for a new alias.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://github.com/wolfwoolford/dish for precisely this purpose. Been using it for years. It's the first thing I install on any new system.